# How do you fade slide in images without skewing in a CSS Grid lay out?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I inherited a website where I can not modify the HTML or the Javascript.  I am only allowed to edit CSS files.

The website has a lot of html components that describe a company's team members, services offered, photo gallery, etc...

The website uses CSS Grid to do a lot of lay outs.

For simplicity sake, I'm going to create some code that demonstrates a problem I'm about to encounter.  Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<style type="text/css">
.our-team {
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template: 50% 50%/30% 15% 15% 40%;
}
.our-team h2 {
  grid-column:1/2;
  grid-row:1/2;
}
.our-team p {
  grid-column:1/2;
  grid-row:2/3;
}
.our-team .img-container:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column:2/4;
  grid-row:1/3;
  z-index:1;
}
.our-team .img-container:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column:3/5;
  grid-row:1/2;
  margin-top:50px;
  z-index:2;
}
.img-window {
  opacity:0;
  width:0;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:opacity 2s ease, width 2s ease;
}
.activate .img-window {
  opacity:1;
  width:100%;
}
img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleImage() {
  var imglist = document.querySelectorAll('.img-container');
  for(var c=0;c<imglist.length;c++) {
    if(imglist[c].className.match(/activate/))
      imglist[c].className='img-container';
    else
      imglist[c].className='img-container activate';
  }
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button onClick="toggleImage();">toggle</button>
      <div class="our-team">
        <h2>Our Team</h2>
        <p>We like to look to brush our teeth with tooth paste</p>
        <div class="img-container">
          <div class="img-window">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBb4v.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="img-container">
          <div class="img-window">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBb4v.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when you press the `toggle` button, some images that are laid out in a fancy manner (ie. not to any traditional boot strap grid system) will fade and slide open.

**Here's the problem:**  You'll notice that the squares in the grid are expanding when fading into view, and the squares in the grid are compressing when fading out of view.  I do not want this compression and expansion behaviour.

If I were allowed to introduce javascript code (which I'm not) and I could edit the CSS code (which I can), I would do something like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<style type="text/css">
.our-team {
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template: 50% 50%/30% 15% 15% 40%;
}
.our-team h2 {
  grid-column:1/2;
  grid-row:1/2;
}
.our-team p {
  grid-column:1/2;
  grid-row:2/3;
}
.our-team .img-container:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column:2/4;
  grid-row:1/3;
  z-index:1;
}
.our-team .img-container:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column:3/5;
  grid-row:1/2;
  margin-top:50px;
  z-index:2;
}
.img-window {
  opacity:0;
  width:0;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:opacity 2s ease, width 2s ease;
}
.activate .img-window {
  opacity:1;
  width:100%;
}
img {
  height:100%;
  display:block;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleImage() {
  var imglist = document.querySelectorAll('.img-container');
  for(var c=0;c<imglist.length;c++) {
    imglist[c].querySelectorAll('img')[0].style.width = imglist[c].offsetWidth+"px";
    if(imglist[c].className.match(/activate/))
      imglist[c].className='img-container';
    else
      imglist[c].className='img-container activate';
  }
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button onClick="toggleImage();">toggle</button>
      <div class="our-team">
        <h2>Our Team</h2>
        <p>We like to look to brush our teeth with tooth paste</p>
        <div class="img-container">
          <div class="img-window">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBb4v.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="img-container">
          <div class="img-window">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBb4v.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I only made two changes.  I deleted the width for the image specified in the css (ie. remove `img {width:100%}`) and I introduced one line of javascript code to assign an absolute width to the image (ie. `imglist[c].querySelectorAll('img')[0].style.width = imglist[c].offsetWidth+"px";`).

Now when you press the toggle button, the grid images do not have that expansion and compression behaviour.

**How can I achieve similar behaviour WITHOUT modifying the HTML or Javascript? I want the images to fade slide in without any skewing effect.**  The only thing I have to work with are:

- I know the `.activate` class will be added to `.img-container` by some other JS code which is off limits to me
- I can only modify the CSS files

Much of the website is built out using this CSS grid structure. So I want to avoid re-writing existing CSS code whenever possible.

Comment: can you add new js? or you want to achive the example without the js added

Comment: You inherited a site that was already using CSS grid at the time? What a time to be alive.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I can not add any new JS.  I am only allowed to work with CSS.

Comment: @BoltClock that's correct, and there are a lot of components spread over 20 templates.  So I really want to avoid re-writing the CSS code if i don't have to.